# Math numerals and text numerals in mtpro2

Tags: fonts, packages, incompatibility, mtpro

I am using baskerville for my text font and mtpro2 for the math. But the numerals in text and in math are different. After looking at mtpro2 documentation I could not find an option for forcing the text numerals in the math mode. Does anyone know of a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code in the preamble should do what you want:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`9}
```

This should go after you have defined the text font and loaded **mtpro2**

Comment: Tried it, did not work.

Comment: @Hesam Well, with the too scarce information you're giving, it's hard to say more than this.

Comment: What information do you need? I added the code as you instructed after the text font and mtpro2 were loaded and I trashed all auxiliary files but then after typesetting the output has not changed.

Comment: @Hesam Try with the new version

Answer (score 2):

`mtpro2` -- short for "MathTime Pro 2" -- provides *mathmode* fonts only. AFAIK, `mtpro2` only provides "lining" (aka "titling") numerals, but not "oldstyle" (or "textstyle") numerals.

You mention that you're using a Baskerville *text* font: does it feature textstyle/oldstyle numerals? Textstyle numerals probably shouldn't be used in math expressions, especially those that involve subscripts and exponents (superscripts) as the ascenders and descenders of some of these numerals could give rise to confusion. (Try typesetting `$6^{2^4}$` vs `$6^{24}$` with textstyle numerals and not being at least slightly puzzled by the output.)

Only in places such as page numbers and in sectioning divisions is it innocuous to use textstyle numerals if a document features a fair amount of math.

There are packages, such as `mathpazo`, which provide the option `osf` to load oldstyle figures. However, they generally do so only for *textmode* numerals. It's probably not an accident that the mathmode numerals of the `mathpazo` package are all in "lining" or "titling" style.

Comment: This is not even a response to my question. You are telling me that if my text font has osf figures (like baskerville) using them in Math mode is not a good idea. Alright but I still want to do it, how can I? Also what if my text font did not have osf numerals but just different ones? Furthermore LaTeX's default is to use text numerals in math, what happens in mtpro2 is abnormal.

Comment: On which basis do you rest your claim, "LaTeX's default is to use text numerals in math"?

Comment: That is what Walter Schmidt writes in "Using MathTime Professional II fonts with LaTeX". It is the LaTeX guide for the font (as opposed to the TeX guide).

Comment: Thanks. The full quote from this document is: "LATEX's default behavior is to typeset numbers and punctuation in math mode using the \mathrm alphabet, which normally equals the default text font." Well, this statement does apply if the Computer Modern or Latin Modern font families are loaded. However, it does *not* apply for many other font families, including, e.g., `mathpazo` -- even if the `osf` option was specified to request oldstyle numerals in text mode: `mathpazo` will use lining numerals when in math mode. Hence, it is not particularly abnormal for `mtpro2` to use its own numerals...